# With LSP, how to get an "input()" in python that works when entering data using the keyboard

Tags: python, lsp-mode, input-method

Here is a minimal example:

I created and activate a virtual environment:

```
~/BacSable/bac2 $ mkvirtualenv minimal_env



created virtual environment CPython3.10.5.final.0-64 in 651ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/raoul/.virtualenvs/minimal_env, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/raoul/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==22.1.2, setuptools==62.6.0, wheel==0.37.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
```

My script `minimal.py` contains:

```
print("yes I can print")
my_input = input("Do you have a problem? (copy paste your answer)")
print(my_input)
my_input = input("Do you have a problem? (type your answer)")
print(my_input)
```

Completion works well with LSP in the script buffer.
With `C-c C-z` I can switch from script to console and vice-versa.

With `C-c C-c` I run the script and I encounter this problem:

The input works if I copy-paste to enter an answer. However, if I type it, I get an error:

```
Python 3.10.5 (v3.10.5:f377153967, Jun  6 2022, 12:36:10) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("yes I can print")
... my_input = input("Do you have a problem? (copy paste your answer)")
... print(my_input)
... my_input = input("Do you have a problem? (type your answer)")
... print(my_input)

yes I can print
Do you have a problem? (copy paste your answer)yes
yes
Do you have a problem? (type your answer)yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined


>>> print(my_input)
__PYTHON_EL_eval("\ndef __PYTHON_EL_get_completions(text):\n    completions = []\n    completer = None\n\n    try:\n        import readline\n\n        try:\n            import __builtin__\n        except ImportError:\n            # Python 3\n            import builtins as __builtin__\n        builtins = dir(__builtin__)\n\n        is_ipython = ('__IPYTHON__' in builtins or\n                      '__IPYTHON__active' in builtins)\n        splits = text.split()\n        is_module = splits and splits[0] in ('from', 'import')\n\n        if is_ipython and is_module:\n            from IPython.core.completerlib import module_completion\n            completions = module_completion(text.strip())\n        elif is_ipython and '__IP' in builtins:\n            completions = __IP.complete(text)\n        elif is_ipython and 'get_ipython' in builtins:\n            completions = get_ipython().Completer.all_completions(text)\n        else:\n            # Try to reuse current completer.\n            completer = readline.get_completer()\n            if not completer:\n                # importing rlcompleter sets the completer, use it as a\n                # last resort to avoid breaking customizations.\n                import rlcompleter\n                completer = readline.get_completer()\n            if getattr(completer, 'PYTHON_EL_WRAPPED', False):\n                completer.print_mode = False\n            i = 0\n            while True:\n                completion = completer(text, i)\n                if not completion:\n                    break\n                i += 1\n                completions.append(completion)\n    except:\n        pass\n    finally:\n        if getattr(completer, 'PYTHON_EL_WRAPPED', False):\n            completer.print_mode = True\n    return completions\nprint(';'.join(__PYTHON_EL_get_completions(\"y\")))", "<string>")
>>>
```

The interpreter behaves as if I typed `>>>yes` directly (instead of just passing it to `input()` ):

```
>>> yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
>>>
```

Of course I can execute the script from eshell:

```
Welcome to the Emacs shell

~/BacSable/bac2 $ python minimal.py 
yes I can print
Do you have a problem? (copy paste your answer)yes
yes
Do you have a problem? (type your answer)yes
yes
~/BacSable/bac2 $
```

Or

```
~/BacSable/bac2 $ python -i minimal.py 
yes I can print
Do you have a problem? (copy paste your answer)yes
yes
yes
Do you have a problem? (type your answer)yes
yes
yes
>>> my_input
my_input
'yes'
>>>
```

But is there a way to make reading input work by running the script with `C-c C-c`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
```

To solve the problem, I modified the activation of `company` in order to deactivate the mode when we are in the python console launched by `C-c` `C-c` :

```
(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :config
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
  (add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook (lambda () (company-mode -1)) 'append)
  ;; The append argument ensures that it's added to the hook after other functions
  )
```